# insert js variable into html href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essentially, trying to pass different (string) values to a variable

```
if (result == "A")
        finalLink.push("https://pool.wikitolearn.org/images/pool/d/d0/Not-giant-enough-letter-a.jpg");
if (result == "B")
        finalLink.push("https://img.clipartfest.com/a354883c247102b05c1657698b7bc8ed_-letters-b-23-b-boyjpg-the-letter-b-clipart_205-257.jpeg");
if (result == "C")
        finalLink.push("http://dailydropcap.com/images/C-9.jpg");
```

and then send the variable to html href tag

```
<a id="button" href="finalLink">Click me to be redirected to your answer</a>
```

don't know much javascript but in PHP you can do this by adding {{variableHere}}

Comment: `push` is an Array method. Did you mean to make use of an array there?

Comment: didn't know it was an array method. I don't need to use an array I don't think. im trying your answer below and failing so far :(

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: i've never used switch before. To put it into more context, i've created a codepen http://codepen.io/erayner/pen/mRrMVd I think I am getting confused with the variable 'result'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript operates differently. When you do something like you suggested you're still on the server and generating the HTML that **will be** sent to the browser.

When you try the same with Javascript the HTML **is already delivered** and must be **manipulated at run-time**.

For that to work you need to **select the element** you want to modify (in this case easy by using `document.getElementById()` because your link actually has an `id`), then use the DOM API method `DOMelement.setAttribute(attributename, value)`.

```js
var finalLink, result;
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// example: result = "A"
result = "A";

function adjustLink() {
  switch(result) {
      case "A": 
        finalLink = "https://pool.wikitolearn.org/images/pool/d/d0/Not-giant-enough-letter-a.jpg"; 
        break;
      case "B":
        finalLink = "https://img.clipartfest.com/a354883c247102b05c1657698b7bc8ed_-letters-b-23-b-boyjpg-the-letter-b-clipart_205-257.jpeg"; 
        break;
      case "C":
        finalLink = "http://dailydropcap.com/images/C-9.jpg"
        break;
      default:
  }
  button.setAttribute("href", finalLink);
}
```

```html
<a id="button" onclick="console.log(this.getAttribute('href')); return false;">Link</a>
<!-- return false; makes sure the link target is not followed (use only for this demo code) -->
<button onclick="result = 'A'; adjustLink();">Set result = "A"</button>
<button onclick="result = 'B'; adjustLink();">Set result = "B"</button>
<button onclick="result = 'C', adjustLink();">Set result = "C"</button>
```

Comment: That is far too much code to review and check for 2:06 a.m. You will have to figure out on your own. Now you know how to dynamically manipulate an element's attribute value in Javascript (which was your initial question).

Comment: haha, fair enough! just the end part of it anyway though. thanks anways connexo :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
var result = "C";

switch(result) {
 case "A": 
   finalLink = "https://pool.wikitolearn.org/images/pool/d/d0/Not-giant-enough-letter-a.jpg"; 
   break;
 case "B":
   finalLink = "https://img.clipartfest.com/a354883c247102b05c1657698b7bc8ed_-letters-b-23-b-boyjpg-the-letter-b-clipart_205-257.jpeg"; 
   break;
 case "C":
   finalLink = "http://dailydropcap.com/images/C-9.jpg"
  break;
default:
}

$("#button").click(function (e){
 if( $(this).attr("href") == "#!" ){ // checks the current value of "href"
     $(this).attr("href", finalLink)  // sets the value of "href"
       .text("Click me to be redirected to your answer"); 
     e.preventDefault(); // prevents redirecting to the finalLink automatically
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="button" href="#!" class="btn btn-success">Test me</a>
```

Comment: OP asked how to manipulate href attribute. Also, why use jQuery here?

Comment: I edited my answer now, thanks for reminding. I added comments on how to `set` and `get` the `href` attribute. I'm using jQuery here because OP tagged jQuery on this question.